# Input validations on table ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am making app using angularJs app and I have one table in which I am using ng-repeat with texbox in td now I want to validate texbox so I used ng-form
and ng-class but I am getting invalid expression error

my code is

```html
<input name ="abc-pqr-{{item.id}}" 
    ng-model="something"
   ng-class="{'has-error':formName.abc-pqr-{{item.id}}.$dirty}">
```

but not worked then I have tried this

```html
<input name ="abc-pqr-{{item.id}}" 
   ng-model="something"
   ng-class="{'has-error':formName[abc-pqr-{{item.id}}].$dirty}">
```

that also not worked

so can someone suggest me right way to archive this
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

- The syntax is wrong, you should use `ng-class="{...}"` not `ng-class=:{...}`
- You must quote the input name, i.e `ng-class="{'has-error':formName['abc-pqr-{{item.id}}'].$dirty}"` you are actually referring to a (none existing) variable called `abc-pqr-xx`
- When you refer to `$dirty` the input must have a `ng-model`

The correct markup could look like this :

```
<input name="abc-pqr-{{item.id}}"
   ng-model="item.value"  
   ng-class="{'has-error':formName['abc-pqr-{{item.id}}'].$dirty}">
```

Comment: hey @davidkonrad thanx for answer and sorry its typo mistake now can you give answer ?

Answer (score 0):

it just misses the quotes: ng-class="{'has-error':formName[**'abc-pqr-{{item.id}}'**].$dirty}"

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function() {
  this.items = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
});
```

```css
.has-error {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">    
    <form name="formName">
      <input ng-repeat="item in vm.items"
        name="abc-pqr-{{item.id}}" 
        ng-model="tem.value"
        ng-class="{ 'has-error': formName['abc-pqr-{{item.id}}'].$dirty}"/>
    </form>
  </div>
```